# How do I write better worlds using Mystcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mystcraft

I've recently started playing Feed the Beast and started getting into the Mystcraft component. I've got a basic grasp of how to use the pages found in forgotten libraries to spawn decent worlds, but is there a particular method to structuring the pages?

For example, I have a page that specifies a block type, how can I use that in world generation? Do I need certain pages in a book to spawn stable worlds?

Answer (score 4):

I am no expert, but as I have some experience myself and because I see that a lot of people are looking for this info i will post what I know.

The general order in which pages should be placed is:

1. Biomes you want (it helps to put in some biomes twice)
2. Biome Controllers (like Large Biomes, Tiny Biomes, Single Biome)
3. Terrain Modifiers (like Flat, Caveworld, Normal)
4. Celestial bodies. The stars, suns and moons (It's important to know that if you want to control where the celestial bodies rise and set or position/speed *you have to put these pages directly in front of the object they control*. Example: Full Length, Rising, East, Normal Sun)
5. Lighting
6. Weather
7. The Sky (clouds, etc.)
8. Additional features (villages, obelisks, caves. If you want to decide the materials of the tendrils or whatever then place the modifier page before the Tendril page.)

Note 1, that if you want to change the colour of anything in your world, then put the colour page immediately *before* the page it controls/affects.

Note 2, that this order may not be the optimal one, but it seems to work for me :) You should always experiment yourself :P

Answer (score 2):

(Note to people who haven't used mystcraft in a while, the method for getting symbols has recently [version 0.10+] changed from randomly generating worlds to finding symbol pages in the overworld, see [this](http://binarymage.com/wiki/doku.php?id=writing:writing) wiki page for more details)

From the mystcraft wiki [page](http://binarymage.com/wiki/doku.php?id=writing:stable) on writing stable ages the basic approach you need to take to is:

```
The simple question to ask yourself, as a writer, is:
“Would this age make sense if nothing from this category was included?”
```

To write a stable age you need to ensure that at least one of every category of primary symbol is included in your descriptive book, there is not AFAIK a definitive list of primary symbol categories.

[Here](http://binarymage.com/wiki/doku.php?id=writing:symbols) is a list of symbols from the Mystcraft site that explain their functions to some degree.

Direwolf20 has a [mod spotlight](http://youtu.be/sNSkjEvB_f8) that covers all the details of how the new writing system works

Primary symbols are those that specify basic properties of the age such as time flow, lighting, biome, etc; in short any feature of that you would expect a 'real' world to have.

As Dan says there are also some symbols (Dense Ores being the most common example) that are guaranteed to introduce instability into the age.

If you want to practice writing stable ages then you can generate a new creative world which will make a 'Creative Spawned' notebook available that will contain all symbols automatically. Using a separate world will also allow you to easily avoid any problems from bloating your save game with a large number of unwanted worlds

Comment: The *order* of symbol pages in a new Description Book now matters too, apparently.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Details on order would be great, but I've failed at finding any. I did see it mentioned in the Direwolf video, but nothing that breaks it down like I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the more normal your age is the more stable (less prone to [decay](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Decay)) it will be. Conflicting symbols in your linking books also decreases its stability. For example, applying "eternal day" *and* "eternal night", or any two symbols from many of the same categories. Selecting "single biome" and then enabling several biomes isn't a good idea either.

Dense ores will always cause fast decay, and features such as glowstone crystals will increase instability. Meteors purportedly *increase* stability (of course you have to deal with meteors.)

Comment: I understand the process of writing a new book, my question is more about how to write better worlds. How the pages interact, what particular pages do, what I should avoid, etc.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that is no longer accurate. Now you have to get pages rather than randomly visiting worlds to get aspects (I think this was how it use to work?)

Comment: @Rapida Your question didn't give the impression you knew about writing desks. What version of Mystcraft are you running?

Comment: @Dan that section in the Technic wiki doesn't seem to have been updated for mystcraft 0.10 which introduced significant changes, and is also the version included in the most recent versions of the various FTB packs

Comment: @DanRasmussen "I've got a basic grasp of how to use the pages found in forgotten libraries to spawn decent worlds" was intended to show I've written worlds. I'm sorry that was unclear, but as Steven pointed out 0.10 is much different than what you are currently describing

Comment: @Rapida Huh, apparently when I last played I'd had a much older version. Good to know. Is the FTB Wiki up-to-date on its information? I didn't seem to see any conflicting articles when I briefly looked over it to post this answer. (I edited my answer to no longer include outdated info. Hopefully now it no longer deserves the -1...)