# Regenerate ores in active minecraft map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

We have a server that is running the Direwolf20 modpack from Feed the Beast. When the server was started we decided to remove GregTech from the modpack. Well now we want to add GregTech back. The problem is because the map is active we don't want to redo everything to get all of the new ores from the mod.

Is there a way to regenerate the map without nuking the world we created?

I have seen people talk about things like MCedit and World Edit but I not am looking to make changes to the world (buildings, entities, towns, etc.) per se, just populate new ores in existing chunks (and new chunks of course).

What is the best recource to this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure there even is a solution. But can't you make a new mystcraft age to mine for the new ores over there?

Comment: Honestly with Myst installed you should just look there for the new ores. Some mods will infact allow you to do a regen pass again but I do not believe Greg Tech is one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three straightforward ways that you can get the newly added worldgen from any mod to be present in your existing world.

- Go far enough away from your currently explored areas to cause the game to generate new chunks (this doesn't require using MCedit / WorldEdit)
- Use a version of MCedit that knows about (and won't replace with air) mod created blocks to delete already explored chunks which, when recreated, will contain the new worldgen. This has the downside of deleting anything you've build in the chunks, but if all the construction on the map is confined to a small area with the rest of the explored area effectively being 'wild' then it can effective.
- Use mystcraft to generate a new age. With the new age creation mechanics in the latest versions of mystcraft this is more complicated than in earlier versions but still fairly straightforward. The easiest way to create a new stable (vitally important) age for the purpose of getting access to new worldgen is to go into creative mode and get a 'creative spawned' mystcraft notebook that will automatically contain all symbols and then follow a guide such as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108725/how-do-i-write-better-worlds-using-mystcraft/108736#108736) to assemble the right symbols in the right order to get a stable age.

Comment: Yeah we had thought about mystcraft, but most people did not like that idea. What about the "re-create" mode in the minecraft client is that of any help to my situation?

Comment: The 're-create' mode allows you to start over from scratch on the exact same map, so it won't help for this particular situation.

Comment: We ended up embracing mystcraft, I have to say I am really enjoying it. So while its not really a "solution" per se. It does allow us to continue on the same map. So this question is done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use nbt tool kit to make ores regenerate if that is what you want.

[here is the link via minecraftforum.net](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1260704-nbtoolkit-oregen-add-new-ores-to-old-maps-and-more).